# Sorting elements alphabetically inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

The data refers to a csv file. Each record of data has a subject. I aim to draw one chart per subject, but I want charts to be sorted alphabetically.

Is there any api to do that for me?

```
data.subjects.forEach(function (subject) {
    //draw chart for subject
    renderChart(subject.name, subject.scores);
}
```

Comment: Sort within  forEach loop ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want charts to be sorted alphabetically

Assuming your `data.subjects` is an Array , you can do :

```
data.subjects.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name< b.name) return -1;
    if(a.name> b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
})
```

nb Notice lowerCase issues which can be solved via :

```
data.subjects.sort(function(a, b){
        var m1 = a.name.toLowerCase();
        var m2 = b.name.toLowerCase();
        if(m1< m2) return -1;
        if(m1> m2) return 1;
        return 0;
    })
```

Comment: Nice to see someone else who thinks the same way as I do and considers case when sorting.

Comment: @Archer Tnx. there is another thing which is `toLocaleLowerCase` but that's another story